# django models sum field from foreign key relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have a one to many relationship.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    stuff

class Item(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to make a query to select all rows in Invoice and the sum of the price of all the items for each invoice, and access it through a queryset

e.g.
so if `invoice #1` has `2 items`, each with `qty=2` and `unit_price=3`, `invoice #1` would have `amount 2x2x3 = $12`

UPDATE:

Here is what I have so far but it gives me a traceback

```
inv_list = \
Invoice.objects.select_related().all()\
.aggregate(sum=sum('item__unit_price')).order_by('-inv_date')

TypeError at /site/invoice/
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the inputs, I took some queues and in the end I created a new column `unit_amount`, added an extra action to the `.save()` method to do `prod_qty * unit_price` and save it to the new column.

and then did this:

```
inv_list = Invoice.objects.all()\
.annotate(amount=Sum('item__unit_amount')).order_by('-inv_date')
```

Comment: Are you sure all your unit_price are int in your database?

Answer (score 2):

If you do `select_related()` then I think you should do `.aggregate(sum=sum('unit_price'))`, right? Still `select_related()` seems to be way to much.

Also `aggregate` will give you a dictionary `{sum:value}`, so ordering seems to be a mistake? What is it for? Not sure about that though. :)

If this doesn't work how about trying this a bit different?

```
for invoice in Invoice.objects.all():
    tmp = invoice.item_set.aggregate(sum=sum('unit_price'))
    # do some stuff with sum
```

Because I believe you want to have sum per invoice, not global sum. Give it a try.

// EDIT: Of course I forgot about quantity. In that case infrared's code is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
for invoice in Invoice.objects.all():
    ammount = 0
    for item in invoice.item_set.all():
        ammount += item.qty * item.unit_price
        print invoice.pk, ammount
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `F()` expressions [were refactored](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) [in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) this has become simple and straightforward:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Invoice.objects.annotate(Sum(F('item__unit_price') * F('item__qty')))
```